# How to make plot titles more legible with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm running some ML algorithms and I have to output 25 plots, all same dataset but different values of lambda and sigma. Now the way they are outputting isn't ideal as you can't read the titles to know what the corresponding lambda, sigma values are. It also gives me an error when I use `plt.tight_layout()` saying `UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes width small enough to accommodate all axes decorations` - which makes sense, I assume there's too many plots on one line to do this. Is there a way to do this 5x5 or do I need to split up the plots differently?

```
sigma_lst = np.logspace(1, 10, 5)
lambda_lst = np.logspace(1, 10, 5)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5,figsize=(15,15))

for lam in range(lambda_lst.shape[0]):
    for sig in range(sigma_lst.shape[0]):
        c = regularizedKernLSTrain(Xtr, Ytr, 'gaussian', sigma=sigma_lst[sig], lam=lambda_lst[lam])
        separatingFKernRLS(c, Xtr, Ytr, 'gaussian', sigma=sigma_lst[sig], Xte=Xts, axs=axs[lam,sig])
        axs[lam,sig].set_title('sigma = ' + str(sigma_lst[sig]) + ', lambda = ' + str(lambda_lst[lam]))

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a list of suggestions to save space:

1. put ticks and labels only on the y axes of the plots in the leftmost column
2. similarly, put ticks and labels only on the x axes of the plots in the bottom row
3. truncate the values for sigma and lambda to exponential notation.
4. only put values for sigma at the top of the corresponding column, and values for lambda at the left of the corresponding row
5. use Greek letters for sigma and lambda (λ and σ)

Comment: I put the axes only on the left and bottom accordingly - thanks for that! But how do I truncate the values?

Comment: @MOA: for example, `'%.1e' % 123.455` gives `'1.2e+02'`. See here for details https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec